# Graphlab Sframe - Remove an empty column

Tags: python, dataframe, graphlab, sframe

I have many sframes each having around 25 columns, I need to run many different classifiers on these. But, there are few columns which would be completely empty for particular Sframes. I need to get a list of columns which are empty for particular sframe, so that I can remove them. And the list would help me keep track of them when I need to remove the same columns for test data. That is, I need a list of columns for each sframe, which are completely empty in that sframe.

I could not figure out how to do that.

Please advice. Thanks